# Performing K-Means Clustering on One Dimensional Array

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to do some K-Means clustering on a one-dimensional array. However, I always get this error "fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X.' According to some other posts it is possible to do KMeans clustering on a one-dimensional array but I keep getting errors.

I know it may not be the best method for one dimension, but I think my PI asked me to it so I can do multiple dimensions later.

Here is my code:

```
patients = df.loc[df['Group'] != 0]

Cranial_Volumes = patients['EstimatedTotalIntraCranialVol_1']

Cranial_Volumes = Cranial_Volumes[~np.isnan(Cranial_Volumes)]

Cranial_Volumes = Cranial_Volumes.values.reshape(1, -1)

KMeans.fit(Cranial_Volumes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make an instance of KMeans before calling the fit method:

```
km = KMeans()
km.fit(Cranial_Volumes)
```